# PHP emailer to provide answer to checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox

Got some great help yesterday with some php code for a mailer and forgot that I also need to know how to include the code so the mailer knows which option is checked in the checkbox. It is a simple 'join mailing list' option with only a yes or no option available.

Code is as follows:

```
    <?php
    $state = 0;
    // check to see if verificaton code was correct
    if(md5($verif_box).'a4xn' == $_COOKIE['tntcon']){
    // if verification code was correct send the message and show this page
    mail("myemail@gmail.com", 'Online Form: '.$subject, "\n".$message." 

    \n\n".$name."\n\n".$lastname."\n\n".$from."\n\n".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."        \n\n".'mailinglist: '.$mailinglist, "From: $from");
   // delete the cookie so it cannot sent again by refreshing this page
   setcookie('tntcon','');
    $state = 2;
    } else if(isset($message) and $message!=""){
    // if verification code was incorrect then return to contact page and show error
    $state = 1;
    }

    if ($state == 0) {  ?>
```

I tried playing with this a bit to see if I could figure it out, but thought I would stop before I get ahead of myself and totally mess it up:

```
   <td align="left"><input type=checkbox name="mailinglist" id="mailinglist"     value="1<?php echo $_GET['mailinglist'];?>">Yes<input type=checkbox name="mailinglist"  id="mailinglist" value="2<?php echo $_GET['mailinglist'];?>">No<font face="Verdana"  size="3" color="#666666"></font><br> </td></tr><tr valign="top" align="right"> <td  nowrap><font face="Verdana" size="3" color="#666666">comments (<span class="R">*</span>)</font></td>
```

Comment: What was the previous question?

Comment: @Braveyard, Previous question from yesterday was correcting a redirect issue. New question is how to have the email sent say mailinglist: yes or no depending on the option checked.

Comment: `md5($verif_box).'a4xn'` is a joke of a method of verification. Don't do it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the email to say whether the user selected Yes for maling list do the following:

```
<td align="left">
<input type="radio" name="mailinglist" value="Yes" /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="mailinglist" value="No" /> No
</td>
```

and in the email you can print the selection as:

```
Mailing list: <?= $_POST['mailinglist'] ?>
```

assuming that you used method POST for form submission

Comment: Post method is used. That is what I wanted to accomplish. Thank you kindly. Much appreciated!

Comment: Use "radio" instead of "checkbox" so the user can make one selection only